# Python DB data pull loop

Tags: python, sql, pandas, database

I want to loop through a script that pulls data from a db 1 month at a time where I am manually updating the date parameters(input) and output file names, but I do not know how I would set up the structure to loop/iterate through the script based on a list of dates/file names.  Due to the size/nature of the datapulls, it does not make sense to pull everything and then split out later in the code.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
import openpyxl

print(datetime.datetime.now())
month = '2022-01-31' # update date here, .xlsx filename and sheet name from jan to feb to march, etc and then the corresponding datetime from 2022-01-31 to 2022-02-28, etc, etc
# I want to iterate through a series of lists as solution:

#potential variable lists:
#month = ['2022-01-31', '2022-02-28', '2022-03-31'] etc.. this populates db/sql injection with each loop through
#month_file_name = ['jan','feb','mar'] etc, this populates filenames with each loop through

sql = pd.read_sql('''select col1, col2, col3 from schema.table where table.asofdate = to_date(:month, 'YYYY-MM-DD')''',sql_engine, params={'month':month})

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(r'\\desktop\output\output_jan.xlsx', engine = 'xlsxwriter')
sql.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='jan_recon', index = False)
writer.close()
print(datetime.datetime.now())
```

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Comment: I took a shot at clarifying, please let me know if this is helpful

Answer (score 1):

You want to loop over a zip() merge of your two lists and where appropriate use f-strings. Nott here that `sql_engine` is undefined.

```py
import pandas as pd

months = ['2022-01-31', '2022-02-28', '2022-03-31']
month_names = ['jan', 'feb', 'mar']
sql_query = '''select col1, col2, col3 from schema.table where table.asofdate = to_date(:month, 'YYYY-MM-DD')'''

for month, month_name in zip(months, month_names):
    sql = pd.read_sql(sql_query, sql_engine, params={'month':month})
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(fr"\\desktop\output\output_{month_name}.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter')
    sql.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=f'{month_name}_recon', index=False)
    writer.close()
```

Comment: this is awesome, i will check it out later this afternoon and respond with feedback!  thank you!